# Use the Laws of Logarithm to expand: $4\log(x)- \frac{1}{3}\log(x^2+1)+2\log(x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For this question I got

$$\log \Biggl(\frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^{1/3}(x-1)^2}\Biggr)$$

However, the answer key in the book has $(x-1)^2$ in the numerator. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4\log x- \frac13\log(x^2+1)+2\log(x-1)\\=\log x^4- \log(x^2+1)^\frac13+\log(x-1)^2\\\text{remember PEMDAS:} \\\underbrace{\log x^4- \log(x^2+1)^\frac13}_{\log \dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^\frac13}}+\underbrace{\log(x-1)^2}_{\text{combine }afer} \\ \therefore \log \frac{x^4(x-1)^2}{(x^2+1)^\frac13}$$

Comment: Okay. I got it.